# Can't import the lib from tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I try to import some library from tensorflow. `from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`. But the terminal said ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.wrappers'. But I found the way out is to use.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

But now I want to import this one `from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor` .
But when I used the same method as before it doesn't work.

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
```

I already check the version of the tensorflow that I have by using pip show tensorflow. It said my version of tensorflow is Version: 2.15.0. And with the same step I check my version of scikit_learn it is version: 1.3.2.

My python version is 3.10.1

So the question is how can I fix this. And how to import the KerasRegressor.

I already search though the google but still didn't find anything.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`KerasRegressor` is not part of Keras anymore (in the latest versions), you can find it in the `scikeras` library.

https://adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/generated/scikeras.wrappers.KerasRegressor.html